# Adding up integers from extracted data

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a code that extract the integers values from a website. I am wondering if i could add up all this integers and display the total sum as well.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("http://www.lelong.com.my/Auc/List/BrowseAll.asp");

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$class = "CatLevel1";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    echo str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    echo '<br/>';
}    
?>
```

Desired Output:
9768
9321
11407
31611
36506

Total: 345664

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it up like a normal variable. Initialize zero on the top. Example:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    echo '<br/>';

    $total += (int) $number;
}

echo "Total: $total";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the integers to a variable and add them with each iteration of `foreach`

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    echo str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    $total += $span->item(1)->nodeValue;
    echo '<br/>';
}
echo "Total: ".$total;
```

**Update:** Make sure what you're getting in `$span->item(1)->nodeValue)` are integers and not string. You can modify `$total += $span->item(1)->nodeValue;` to `$total += intval($span->item(1)->nodeValue);` to convert a returning string like "97" to an `int` 97.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code does 90% of what you want to do and the adding of integers should be relatively simple in comparison.

Assuming this part is returning your integers:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    echo str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Change it to this:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $integer = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $span->item(1)->nodeValue);
    $total += $integer;
    echo "$integer<br/>";
} 
echo "Total: $total";
```